# Pyspark : Deleting/Removing rows with conditions

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe which looks like this

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([("1", "INSERT"),("2", "INSERT"),("3", "INSERT"), ("2", "MODIFY"), ("1", "DELETE"), ("3", "DELETE"), ("4", "INSERT")], ["id", "label"])
df.show()
```

```
+---+------+
| id| label|
+---+------+
|  1|INSERT|
|  2|INSERT|
|  3|INSERT|
|  2|MODIFY|
|  1|DELETE|
|  3|DELETE|
|  4|INSERT|
+---+------+
```

I'm trying to remove rows based on a condition that , those rows which have label as 'DELETE' which also has a 'INSERT' label with same id has to be removed

so the result would be something like:

```
+---+------+
| id| label|
+---+------+
|   |      |
|  2|INSERT|
|  2|MODIFY|      
|  4|INSERT|

+---+------+
```

tried used something like filter in pyspark

```
df.filter("label !='DELETE' AND id !='1'").show()
```

but not sure how to put more conditions.
Do not want to use pandas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame([("1", "INSERT"),("2", "INSERT"),("3", "INSERT"), ("2", "MODIFY"), ("1", "DELETE"), ("3", "DELETE"), ("4", "INSERT")], ["id", "label"])

df.groupBy(df.id).agg(F.collect_list(df.label).alias('labels')) \
    .where((~ F.array_contains(F.col('labels'), 'DELETE'))) \
    .select(df.id, F.explode(F.col('labels')).alias('label')) \
    .show()
```

output:

```
+---+------+
| id| label|
+---+------+
|  4|INSERT|
|  2|MODIFY|
|  2|INSERT|
+---+------+
```

- Group by `id` and `collect_list(label)`;
- Filter out rows containing `DELETE`;
- Restore to the original row with `explode()`.

**It should be noted that this does not preserve the original row order, nor does it save rows with null label**.

If you have other columns, You can try the following code. There is no aggregation on the original DF, so other normal columns will not be affected.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame([("5", None, 'columnTest'), ("1", "INSERT", 'columnTest'), ("2", "INSERT", 'columnTest'),("3", "INSERT", 'columnTest'), ("2", "MODIFY", 'columnTest'), ("1", "DELETE", 'columnTest'), ("3", "DELETE", 'columnTest'), ("4", "INSERT", 'columnTest')], ["id", "label", 'columnTest'])

ids = df.where(df.label == 'DELETE') \
    .groupBy(df.label).agg(F.collect_set(df.id).alias('ids')).collect()[0]['ids']

df.where(~ df.id.isin(ids)).show()
```

output：

```
+---+------+----------+
| id| label|columnTest|
+---+------+----------+
|  5|  null|columnTest|
|  2|INSERT|columnTest|
|  2|MODIFY|columnTest|
|  4|INSERT|columnTest|
+---+------+----------+
```

- Get all id of `DELETE`;
- Just filter out rows id in `ids`.

**This preserves the original row order and the label field with null value.**

Comment: Thank you for the answer Guoran Yun. Also, what if I have other columns which has nothing to do with comparing or conditions but I still want to retrieve it. From your code, if I have a dataframe with more columns which do not have any part in comparisons or conditions and i run this code , I receive only id and lable columns in output dataframe. How do I alter the code?

Comment: Apologies @GuoranYun for not mentioning other columns (which are not part of conditions) as well earlier

Comment: @Mahesh M Don't be too polite. I updated the answer. You can have a look.

Comment: @Mahesh M Does this update solve your problem?

Comment: Yes. Marking as solution!